# How do Natsu and Happy get into Lucys house?

Tags: fairy-tail

Just wondering but how does Natsu and Happy end up breaking into Lucy's house? I am wondering on this since I heard a recent rumor that...

> Mirajane has a spare key to Lucy's home and often gives the key to Natsu and Happy

I also wanted to ask this question since when Lucy comes home or gets out of the shower, Natsu and Happy seem to be there. Of course though it is only a rumor, but is there anything to go against this or any information to say this is true or not? I trust this site so that is why I am asking it here.

Answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: Natsu and Happy aren't the only ones who can sneak into Lucy's house. Example: Cana in [Episode 97](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Best_Partner)

Comment: Personally, I think that they do it because Hiro Mashima is a true NaLu (Natsu x Lucy) supporter, so he makes them do it.

Comment: Pretty sure they just go through a window haha I mean it shows them jumping out all the time, so why not jump in?

Comment: don't know about mirajane but landlady does have a spare key. and also natsu is most powerful mage and hero of the series . so why can't he go into the heroine's house without asking.. ;)

Answer (score 7):

What you have heard is not a rumour, this reason is mentioned in Fairy Tail manga volume 6 Q&A.

> Mirajane has an extra copy of her house key which she gives to the other members so that they can enter Lucy's house.

I don't have a copy of this volume now so I cannot confirm it myself, but it has been posted on the Fairy Tail wiki, and a number of other sites.